# Android: Show the same item randomly after the array has been finished

Tags: android, arrays

I have a part on my code, where I show randomly in a `TextView` the items from an array in `strings.xml`
The problem is that I don't have so many items and most of the times, it shows the same, even after it has been already shown..
Is there any way to show the same item randomly only after the array has been finished and has seen all the items?? Then start again from the beginning and do the same..
The part of code is:

```
private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();
......

Resources res = getResources();
myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.My_Array);
String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
textView.setText(q);
```

Thank you!!

Comment: You may remember items shown in a bit array and choose first false item after rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length) item. When all true reset it back to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps -

```
TextView tvData;
SparseBooleanArray stringsShown;
Button btnShowRandom;
int arraySize;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvData);
    btnShowRandom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowRandom);
    Resources res = getResources();
    myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.string_array_data);
    arraySize = myString.length;
    stringsShown = new SparseBooleanArray();
    setShownArray();
    // event on which random items is to be shown
    btnShowRandom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showRandomText(rgenerator.nextInt(arraySize));
        }
    });
}

private void showRandomText(int position) {
    if (isAllItemShown()) {
        //reset array
        setShownArray();
    }
    if (!stringsShown.get(position)) {
        String q = myString[position];
        stringsShown.put(position, true);
        tvData.setText(q);
    } else {
        showRandomText(rgenerator.nextInt(arraySize));
    }
}

private boolean isAllItemShown() {
    for (int i = 0; i < stringsShown.size(); i++) {
        if (!stringsShown.get(i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private void setShownArray() {
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        stringsShown.put(i, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask one more thing?? Could you add me a row so not shown the same array item right after it has been shown?? I notice that when my array finished, some times, it shows from the beginning the last item..